# How can I test a OPC-UA server running on Raspberry Pi from a Windows computer?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, opc-ua, node-opcua

As a part of a job assignment where I am to implement and test an OPC server on a Raspberry Pi, I found and implemented a *node.js* server found at [this Github repository](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/tree/master/documentation) (sample_server.js).

Now, being new to OPC in general, I tried downloading the *MatrikonOPC Explorer* to connect to the server, but it refused to find the server. At first I thought I was just not putting in the right things (endpoint URL goes somewhere?) into the connect prompt, but having read some more, (I think) I now understand that the explorer uses the regular OPC specification while my server is a OPC-UA server. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Anyway, I would like to see if this server actually works and can be accessed. What is a good way of testing this? If possible, I would like to test it over the network, from my Windows PC (they are both on the same network, and I have ensured they are pingable from eachother).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my suspicion was right - the problem was solved by adding a *UA proxy* that translated the OPC-UA to OPC Classic, allowing the explorer to detect and access the server.